# Splash screen with Tabbed main page Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner in mobile app development and I'm developing an android app using Xamarin forms for a project.

On my Xamarin forms project, I have to add a splash screen at startup. to accomplish this I have to put this code on my MainPage.XAML

```
<Grid>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Grid x:Name="SplashGrid" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
            <Image x:Name="Logo" Source="Logo" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image.TranslationY>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <On Platform="Android">-12</On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Image.TranslationY>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

But my main page is a Tabbed page and not a content page.

What can I do to achieve a splash screen while my main page remains tabbed?

if my tabbed page can be opened automatically after loading the main page, that would be fine too.

this is how the constructor of my App.xaml.cs looks.

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPageContainer()); 
        }
```

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        // show the splash
        MainPage = new SplashPage();
        // simple wait or initialize some services
        await Task.Delay(2000); 
        // show the real page
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPageContainer()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe Splash is something we display till the time app load its first page just to avoid that empty screen, If you are assign splash inside App.cs then it will work nothing like but the first page only, which in deed will have empty screen at the start up.

Comment: @MShah Please have a look at the question: The OP posted code with the Splash image on MainPage - but he cannot use it any longer because now the app is using a NavigationPage with a TabbedPageContainer

Comment: But what can be done is creating splash activity like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-splash-screen-for-android-app-in-xamarin/

Comment: In this way it will work as Splash screen and launch directly the tabbed page only

Comment: @MShah OP said: *On my Xamarin forms project, I have to add a splash screen at startup. to accomplish this I have to put this code on my MainPage.XAML* - feel free to post an answer by yourself, but to me my answer is exactly that what the OP has asked for (Splash image on a page)

Comment: **This code really works** 
but the splash screen doesn't appear the way I expected. 
I'll try to play with my code a little bit.

Thank you so much for the help @SirRufo

Comment: @MShah I think the link you provide is about a Xamarin.Android splash screen. if you can provide any answer in Xamarin forms I really appreciate it.

Comment: @KLM in iOS the splash screens will be placed inside assets Folder or we can create launch storyboard, so you have to go platform specific for creating splash.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we use drawable resource to create the splash screen. Follow the stpes below.

You could follow the stpes on the link below. It works well on tabbed page.
[Xamarin forms custom splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915394/xamarin-forms-custom-splash-screen/59925645#59925645)

[image]

For more about IOS, you could check the link.

https://medium.com/@thesultanster/xamarin-splash-screens-the-right-way-3d206120726d
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen