# How set either of two first pages in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that is derived from the Pullout Menu tutorial. It has five pages; let's call them A, B, C, D and E. A is listed as the first FlyoutItem in AppShell.xaml and it is the first page the user sees on startup.

I would like to vary that under program control. I would like under condition X to have B be the first page the user sees, else A. (The user would be free to navigate as wished from there on using the pullout menu.)

I tried following [Splash screen with Tabbed main page Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184770/splash-screen-with-tabbed-main-page-xamarin-forms) but (a.) when I added an `OnStart()` with `if (X) MainPage = new BPage();` the app starts up with a black page with no controls or "features" whatsoever, not my B page; and (b.) `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPageContainer());` will not compile. (I guess `TabbedPageContainer` is wrong for a pullout App but I don't know what to use instead.)

How do I accomplish programmatic control of the first page seen by the user in a Xamarin Forms Pullout Menu app?

At @Jason's suggestion, this might be the relevant portion of AppShell.xaml:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="A" Icon="..."> <ShellContent Route="APage" 
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:APage}" /> 
</FlyoutItem> 
<FlyoutItem Title="B" Icon="..."> <ShellContent Route="BPage" 
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BPage}" /> 
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Where is your code?  You mention that you are following a specific tutorial but didn't provide a link, so we have no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: Shoot. Sorry, @Jason . I somehow thought people would be familiar with the MS Xamarin tutorials. Now I can't even find it. What do you want to know about the code? I obviously can't post the whole thing here. Maybe I just started from Win VS 2019 "New Project" and selected Xamarin Forms with Pullout Menu? Does that make sense?

Comment: I've gotten a little closer. I added MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyApp.Views.BPage()); It starts up with the heading for BPage visible but nothing else. No hamburger menu and none of the controls of BPage.

Comment: I'd suggest that you post the relevant portions of your AppShell xaml and indicate which pages you want to be able to set as the start page.  Setting `MainPage` is NOT the correct way to solve this

Comment: AppShell.xaml is 155 lines. Not sure which are relevant. I have

Comment: <FlyoutItem Title="A" Icon="...">
        <ShellContent Route="APage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:APage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="B" Icon="...>
        <ShellContent Route="BPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

Comment: I want BPage to be first if (X) else APage.

Comment: please edit your post, do not stuff code in comments

Comment: > Setting MainPage is NOT the correct way to solve this. I get that. My question is "what is?" I'm open. I am not arguing for doing this one particular way. I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `CurrentItem` property

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // use x:Name to assign names to your FlyoutItem
    if (someCondition) {
        CurrentItem = FlyoutA;
    } else {
        CurrentItem = FlyoutB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Yes! I don't have all of my "someCondition" figured out yet but this is the answer to my question.