# Load startup model in platform project code and pass it to PCL on Xamarin Forms Initialization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

The application I'm currently working on requires data to be retrieved from a web service during app startup that roughly takes 1.5 seconds. After the data is retrieved, it needs to be displayed on the MainPage and that is another 1.5 - 2 seconds since the data is mostly URLs of images that have to be displayed, in my case, using `ffimageloading` library; which means actually downloading those images first to be displayed.

I have splash startup screens for both `Android` and `iOS` implemented separately in platform projects but splash screen only stays up for the amount of time `Xamarin Forms` needs to load and afterwards disappears not waiting for my actual model to load from the web service. I have searched for solutions to extend the splash screen duration and mostly every solution I have read involves creating another splash screen page, loading page if you will, that is already controlled in `PCL` project but having two separate splash loading screens just seams not feasible to me at the moment.

So I was wondering, how would one load the initial model in platform projects, during the actual splash screen, and then later pass it to `PCL` project when `Xamarin Forms` has finished initialization, presumably to `App.xaml.cs` 's `App()` constructor function?

Comment: Can you post some code?  Android only?

Comment: @Prateek I mentioned I have splash for both Android and iOS, there is no relevant code to post.

Comment: Is there SplashScreen in iOS ? as far as I know there its called Launch Screen, it differs from Splash. "implemented separately" if there is no code then it would be hard for people to help you out.  Please check [Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help) especially [MCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Prateek For both platforms, my implementations of splash and launch screens are taken from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen).

Comment: You could use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` before `LoadApplication(new App());`. It would delay the splash screen. I make the splash screen according to thr link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915394/xamarin-forms-custom-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

There is no code or enough details so I am assuming this is what you want to do.
Call the APIs asynchrnously , till then show splash screen.

Before assigning `MainPage` in your App.xaml.cs you should call these APIs asynchronously with await and then you use the same for binding of your mainpage

```cs
public App()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    //do all my prefetch stuff for app initialization.
    // API and what not

    var viewmodel = new AppMainViewModel();
    await viewmodel.CallFooFetchAsync();
    await viewmodel.BlahBlahAsync();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppMainPage(viewmodel));
}
```

In Page

```cs
public AppMainPage(AppMainViewModel vm)
{
    BindingContext =vm;
}
```

So by the time page loads it has all the data handy.

You can explore adding this code in `OnAppearing` of the page.

Note that the concept of default Splash screen is just to show an image(with different theme in Android) and setting image in iOS. You need to have conventional UI technically its not splash screen anymore.

Alternatively you can get shared project handle in native

Android Sp

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
...
    var app = new App(); //this will be shared project App object
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await app.DoPrefetchStuffFirst()); //API calls if needed in this async method

    //then
    LoadApplicationm(app)
}
```

You can do similar thing in iOS AppDelegate

And if you call native specific methods in platforms (may be for API calls) then you would use `DependencyService` feature , that will pass it to shared project or Custom renderer based on where you want to use it.