# Xamarin Android - Splash screen doesn't show on release on device

Tags: android, xamarin, splash-screen

Simple application. I have added a splash screen and it works on:
- debug version with emulator
- release version with emulator
- release version when the phone is connected on the computer

But - it doesn't show if I install the release APK file on the phone. What can be the reason?

Here is code:

```
namespace Splash_Screen
{
    [Activity(Label = "Splash Screen App", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class SplashScreen : MainActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashScreen).Name;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
}
```

and a second part:

```
       public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//get data info
            PodatkiNaprave();
//get results
            DobiRezultate();
        }
```

and a splash part of styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">  
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>  
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

and mainactivity:

```
  public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your Splash activity and mainactivity?

Comment: Yes, I edited a question. You can see MainPage and Splash activity.

Comment: and please post MainActivity

Comment: As a noob, I didn't know where MainActivity is :-) now I have found it. Anand, tnx for your time.

Comment: Can you check if you set MainLauncher = true ij just above MainActivity?

Comment: It was set to True. As you suggested, I changed to False.

Comment: @JanezKranjski Try the code in the link below to create the splash screen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915394/xamarin-forms-custom-splash-screen/59925645#59925645 Does the splash screen show on device?

Comment: No. In the last days I tested APK on different devices and there were different behaviors. It didn't work on the first device, on the second device it works very sporadic, on the third it works as it should. I will investigate this more detailed.

Comment: This comment won't help a lot. I changed some stuffs over and there, remove XML and add it again and now it works.

Comment: Sorry. I can't describe what really changed behavior. That was the reason why I didn't post it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this `SplashActivity` code.

```
using Android.Support.V7.App;
namespace Splash_Screen
{
    [Activity(Label = "Splash Screen App", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashScreen).Name;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
}
```

And also make sure that `MainLauncher=False` in `MainActivity`

Comment: I added "using Android.Support.V7.App" (I didn't see more changes in your suggestion). Then I change MainLauncher to False. The results stay the same - it works in Debug, but the splash screen doesn't show on release on the phone.

Comment: changed this line?   public class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity

Comment: you used  public class SplashScreen : MainActivity

Comment: Sorry, I copied your suggestion and there was SplashScreen: AppCompatActivity. Just my report here wasn't complete. But it is still the same.

Comment: Maybe additional information can be helpful: the splash picture is full screen even if I had set "windowFullscreen" to "false" in "styles.xml".